How to correcty burn/overlay teletext subtitles as a bitmap-based subtitles?
I have a TS file with a complete teletext stream. In page 888, there are subtitles.
I managed to overlay them as I wanted using ffmpeg -txt_page 888 -i test.ts -filter_complex "[0:s]scale=1920:1080[subs];[0:v][subs]overlay[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a output.ts
However, many subtitles are missing and some of them linger for a bit.
In VLC (that also uses zvbi), all subtitles show up correctly.
What my be causing this problem? Is there a correct way to do this.
PS.: I don't want to extract them to .srt or using it as middleware and then burning them, as they will loose some special aligments. I want to burn zvbi's output onto the video.

Any way you can share the files, or some samples?

@timbo Yeah, sure: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h-YpAXhaK_QHuqrEQ4MShYiNTEtj3SCM/view?usp=drive_link The subtitles are on page 888

Did you get this idea from the ffmpeg docs? In there, regarding complex filtergraphs, it mentions: ... you can use a bitmap subtitle stream as input.... Note that this is an experimental and temporary solution. It will be removed once libavfilter has proper support for subtitles. Maybe some undocumented change has occurred in the ffmpeg code or the teletext subtitles are not bitmaps? I tried outputting to a mkv container but got the same result. Maybe you have no choice but to output the subs to .srt as an intermediate step?

@FlexMcMurphy Yes, I did, but I didn't know that, tho. Teletext subtitles are text subtitles per se, but you also have the option to display them as bitmaps, in fact it's the default option in -txt_format. Libzvbi is responsible for that, so I thought I could just overlay its output. I think I'll report it in ffmpeg's bug tracker, just to see if anyone knows about this

Yes but libzvbi-teletext is a teletext subtitle decoder? I think use of an overlay still requires an encoder and a decoder and the only ffmpeg subtitle encoder is dvbsub which requires the subs to be in VobSub .idx format. I used that to write a .srt file of subs as a dvb stream to a ts container. I'm not certain but I think converting the subtitle format e.g. from text to image, is not supported by ffmpeg currently. Happy to be corrected on this.

I might be confusing things... perhaps overlays do not need to be encoded again and in my case I was working with softsubs creating a separate dvb subtitle stream in the ts container.
